# Group by with Order in MySQL with Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am running MySQL query (not HQL) with Hibernate. I am trying to use `Group by  desc`  and it gives me exception -

> unexpected token: desc near line 1, column 340

The same query, however, works when I run it in mySQL command line.

Comment: Could you post your query and the method you use to execute it? With `EntityManager` you should use `createNativeQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `desc` is a reserve word and should be escaped using backtique like below. Better yet, don't use reserve word at all (OR) if you had to then try using some other word along with it like `desc_HQL`

```
 Group by  `desc`
```

Comment: You mean I should use it like Group by with `` ?

Comment: Yes, since desc is a reserve word and should be escaped.

Comment: I still get exception - a different one now - org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '`'

Comment: Not sure about hibernate, you will have to find out how to escape a mysql reserve word in hibernate. You can try changing your column name to something other than reserve word if possible as suggested in answer.

Comment: Got the same problem when trying to create a table named match. :)